# Can an answer be turned into a comment/deleted?

Tags: support

[Extension of previous problem, involving $\ell^p$ norm circles](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/5505/extension-of-previous-problem-involving-ellp-norm-circles)

The only answer available was a reply to the original question (what can I use to find the area of each). However, now that I've edited the question, the answer would be much better as a comment. I don't want bounty being awarded for something that isn't an answer, so is there a way to have the answer turned into a comment and/or deleted?

Comment: I think you should't edit your question in a way that makes previously valid answers invalid. You can just ask a new question instead.

Comment: that is a good point, but now that there's a bounty on it, I'm worried that bounty will go to a non-answer... (although the previous answer wasn't too much of an answer either; it just gave me a name of what I was asking for)

Comment: I don't want the bounty either; I don't really have any more time to spend on that question, and I don't want to get something for nothing. Maybe the bounty can be removed for that question, and then you can ask a new question with that bounty?

Comment: The bounty won't be automatically awarded unless the answer gets to +2 vote.

Comment: I like JM's idea of removing the bounty and making a new question with that bounty on it instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The poster of the answer can delete it.  If the poster does not delete it, it probably requires the moderator powers to delete a post.

[There is no way to cancel a bounty](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28297/is-there-any-way-to-cancel-a-bounty-or-prevent-someone-from-automatically-getting).